How to fix this meter display animation from bottom to up using HTML and CSS?
I am working on a Blazor Hybrid Project (Web App) that have a meter display component. This meter display component will display string of numbers that resembles a real meter display. When a new number is about to be displayed, I want the animation to be from bottom to top, to again resemble how a real life meter display animation look like.
Here is what I have. There is no animation currently. the digit just switches :

Here is what I am trying to achieve. Bottom to up animation :

So far, I have tried to create a keyframe slide-up to translate the new digits from bottom to up and push the old one to above area and set the area overflow=hidden. But, upon debugging, it looks like the animation is not working. I used this method based on a tutorial on creating custom keyframes online, and I create this myself. Am I doing this correctly?
CurrentMeterDisplayContainer.razor
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
@implements IDisposable
@using System.Threading

<div class="meter-container">

    <div class="meter-reading">

        @for (int i = 0; i < meterReading.CurrentValue.Length; i++)
        {
            var digit = meterReading.CurrentValue[i];

            <div class="digit-container">

                <div class="digit-slide-up">

                    <span class="@(i >= meterReading.CurrentValue.Length - 2 ? "digit last-digits" : "digit")">@digit</span>

                </div>

            </div>
            
        }

    </div>

</div>

@code {
    private CurrentMeterReadings meterReading = new CurrentMeterReadings();
    private Timer timer;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        meterReading.UpdateReading(); 
        timer = new Timer(_ => UpdateMeter(), null, 0, 5000); 
    }

    private void UpdateMeter()
    {
        meterReading.UpdateReading();
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer?.Dispose();
    }
}

CurrentMeterDisplayContainer.razor.css:
.meter-container {
    padding: 2px;
    /* height: 100%; */
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.meter-reading {
    display: flex;
}

.digit-container {
    /* padding: 1px; */
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.digit {
    font-family: "Bebas Regular";
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    width: 75%;
    height: 85%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.last-digits {
    color: #EF4B4B;
}

.digit-slide-up {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    animation: slide-up 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.16,1,0.3,1) forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-up {
    from {
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

For the model class, its just simple and straight forward. It has a List of int numbers and a function to change the numbers to strings.

I made something like this as an answer to another question here on SO. Does that help give you an idea as one way you could accomplish your design goal?

@asyncawait Thanks. I looked at it, and its a bit different to what I have right now. But the idea is really helpful. Based on your answer, i think i have to add the set of new numbers below the one being displayed and hid it in overflow. then probably it will work.

Glad it helped :) You could pretty easily put the odometer behind an element that just shows the center row, add as many columns as you need, and use some absolute positioning for the relative container to prevent weird display in the flow of your project. Also, there's the libraries that accomplish the design effect I linked in that answer as well, if those are an option. Good luck! If you have any issues let me know.
